# Is querying with implicit type conversion bad?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express

I am in the process of developing a CRUD RESTful API using the Express.js and TypeScript frameworks.

When invoking an endpoint, for instance, ".../user/:id," I extract the value of the 'id,' parameter which is inherently of the string data type. This 'id' value serves as the basis for querying and selecting data from the database.

Within the database table, there is an 'id' column of type serial.

Is it considered bad that I query the database with string value for this 'id' column? What is your recommended way of handling this issue?

Comment: Code that's explicit and verbose is easier to debug and maintain but less convenient to write and possibly harder to read: implicit casts are there for your convenience. That being said, if the db saves the ID as a serial, I'm guessing it originates there, so it only makes sense to make it an integer in your app as well. Are you sure your query parameter binding is set up right? Why are you reading integer-type values as/into strings and supplying strings for comparison with ints?

Comment: @Zegarek PATH parameters are inherently strings, which means that I should cast them to integer first, which also feels "hacky".

Comment: The risk of SQL injection should be of far greater concern than whether or not `:id` is implicitly converted to an integer. Path and query parameters should never be used raw in a query. Use bind variables in the query to guard against SQL injection. Explicit casts are preferable since there are cases where PostgreSQL will not recognize that an implicit cast is possible or might choose to cast differently than the developer expected/intended.

Comment: Postgres **does not have a serial data type**. Specifying *serial* is a  notational convenience for: 1. Define column data type as integer. 2. Create a sequence. 3. Assign the `nextval()` function of the sequence as the default value. 4. Assign ownership to column to the sequence. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). The column has **nothing to do with PATH**.